# Homotopy, topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space.
>
> Let $w$ be path in $X$. $\overline{w}(t)=w(1-t)$ and $\iota_{x}(t)=x$ for every $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in X$.
>
> Give homotopies $H$ and $K$, with
>
> $w\ast\iota_{w(1)}\sim_H w$ and $w\ast\overline{w}\sim_K\iota_{w(0)}$

Hello,

I want to give these homotopies $H$ and $K$. For $H$ I thought about:

$H(s,t)=\begin{cases} w(s), \quad 0\leq s<1\\\iota_{w(1)}(s),\quad s=1\end{cases}$

Therefore this homotopy does not depend on $t$.
And I can give $H$ like this, because $w$ is a path, hence continuous.

And for $K$:

$K(s,t)=\begin{cases} w(s),\quad 0\leq s\leq\frac12\\ w(1-s),\quad\frac12\leq s\leq 1\end{cases}$

which does not depend on $t$ either...

I think this is wrong.
How can I construct those homotopies. What do I have to consider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a linear Homotopy? For instance for the first case we could use $H(s,t)=(1-s)w*i_{\{w(1)\}}(t) + sw(t)$ and we can, this way of reasoning, extend to the other one

Comment: Hint: First clarify what the homotopies you want to construct actually have to satisfy. For example, you need $H(s,0)=\omega(s)$,  while $H(s,1)$ has to be $\omega(2s)$ for $s\leq 1/2$ and $\omega(1)$ for $s\geq 1/2$, and further $H(0,t)=\omega(0)$ and $H(1,t)=\omega(1)$ for all $t$. Once you have clarified that, try to find a function $h:I\times I\to I$ such that $H(s,t)=\omega(h(s,t))$ does the job.